# Как установить обе версии Python 2.x и 3.x на windows7

Tags: python, windows-7

Планирую вести разработку на обеих версиях Python 2.x и 3.x на windows7. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно без конфликта версий их установить и переключаться между ними?
Спасибо!

Comment: достаточно просто установить 2 версии Python, и в Windows можно выбрать как запустить скрипт и можно бывать Python 2 или 3

Answer (score 5):

Поставили 2.x версию, поставили 3.x версию.

После установки убедитесь, что `py.exe` используется для запуска `*.py` файлов (и `pyw.exe` для `*.pyw`):

```
С:\> assoc .py
С:\> ftype Python.File
```

Если хотите запускать `команда.py` файл, как просто `команда`, то добавьте `.py` расширение в `%PATHEXT%` переменную окружения.

Если хочется, чтобы выбранная версия Питона для запуска использовалась, то добавьте [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) на самом верху Питон-скрипта. К примеру, чтобы выбрать Python 2.x:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

Чтобы выбрать Python 3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Можно также явно указывать желаемую версию при старте:

```
C:\> py -3 \путь\команда.py
```

`py -3.5 -m pip install win-unicode-console` запустит команду для Python 3.5 (к примеру, если у вас как Python 3.6 так и 3.5) установлены.

[Есть несколько способов настроить версию по умолчанию](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customization).

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить нужные версии Python, например

   - 2.7.13
   - 3.5.3
   - 3.6.0

   При установке поставить галочку `Add Python x.y to PATH`, если требуется доступ к интерпретаторам в командной строке и не снимать галочку с установки `pip` при кастомизации.
2. Если разработка ведётся через PyCharm, то интерпретатор можно выбрать прямо в настройках `File --> Setting --> Project --> Project Interpreter`. Прямо там можно устанавливать пакеты для каждого интерпретатора. Допустимо также выбирать виртуальные окружения при использовании `virtualenv`.
   [image: Выбор интерпретатора в PyCharm]
3. Если нужно также вызывать `python` через командную строку. Создать копии `python.exe` в каждом из установленных экземпляров (пути для примера типовой установки на x64 машину), например

   - в `C:\Python27`из `python.exe` создать копию `python27.exe`;
   - в `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`из `python.exe` создать копию `python35.exe`;
   - в `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`из `python.exe` создать копию `python35.exe`;

   исходные `python.exe` оставить.
4. После перезапуска командной строки (перезагрузки компьютера --- любой операции, когда обновляются переменные окружения), если все интерпретаторы содержатся в переменной окружения `PATH`, будут доступны команды

   - `D:\>python27 -V
     Python 2.7.13`
   - `D:\>python35 -V
     Python 3.5.3`
   - `D:\>python36 -V
     Python 3.6.0`
5. Запускать скрипты в командной строке теперь можно следующим образом:

   - `D:\>python27 script.py`
   - `D:\>python35 script.py`
   - `D:\>python36 script.py`
6. Установка пакетов в каждый интерпретатор возможно через `pip`

   - `pip2.7 install <имя пакета>`
   - `pip3.5 install <имя пакета>`
   - `pip3.6 install <имя пакета>`

эти экземпляры `pip` устанавливаются сразу с `Python`, их вручную копировать не нужно.