# sublime text 3 и русский язык

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, русификация

вопрос простой: как делать, чтобы ST3 нормально печатал русские буквы?

вот программа для примера:

```
print ('1')
print ('re')
print ('2')
print ('я печатаю')
print ('3')
print ('print')
```

при таком выполнении я получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. теряется не только русский текст, но и соседний английский.

Если я закоменчиваю строку с русским текстом, то получаю полностью рабочую программу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая необъяснимая фигня. ((( Причем вывести закономерность, сколько и какие строки потеряются при наличии русской строки - невозможно. Иногда пропадает ТОЛЬКО русская строка. Иногда - еще 1,2,3,4 соседних английских. Но если в программе русского вывода нет, то все всегда печатается полностью, без глюков и проблемм.

P.S. Сразу скажу: добавление вверху плашки

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

не помогает.

Comment: Проверяйте соответствие кодировок. В какой кодировке файл сохраняется, с какой кодировкой запускается интерпретатор?

Comment: в preferences - settings User у меня прописано  "encoding": "cp1251",
 "fallback_encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)", я их пробовал в разных комбинациях менять и на cp866 и на utf-8. Ничего не добился.

Comment: User New, я бы не рекомендовал использование нативных Build System: это неудобно и не очень функционально, см. [**мой развёрнутый ответ**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934). Вы уже упомянули Console Exec; также порекомендовал бы плагин Terminality, который активно развивается. В Terminality проблема разрешается заменой [**в настройках**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality/blob/master/Terminality.sublime-settings#L51) `UTF-8` на `cp1251`. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, @СашаЧерных именно с вашего (развернутого ответа) я и взял идею о Console Exec. Спасибо. Но с этим есть одна очень бесячая меня проблема. Она изложена в моем вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624377/  Может вы с вашим опытом знаете решение?

Comment: @UserNew: Вам Сmder на англоязычном SO посоветовали. я бы на Вашем месте (лично для меня вот буквы не сливаются, увеличение шрифта в консоли решает проблему) сделал бы feature request в [**репозитории Console Exec**](https://github.com/joeyespo/sublimetext-console-exec/issues), чтобы можно было бы производить вывод в терминал, предпочтительный для юзера (в Вашем случае cmder), а не только дефолтную консоль. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, спасибо за совет и за ссылку. Да, я так и сделал на гитхабе. Попросил их об этой фиче. Если хотите - присоединяйтесь к запросу.

Comment: UserNew, подписался на Вашу issue. Terminality пробовали? Есть проблемы? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: инструментов, которые требуют однобайтовую кодировку использовать для вывода (такую как cp1251), следует избегать. Даже Windows-консоль поддерживает Unicode API для ввода/вывода (используется в Python 3.6, см. win-unicode-console пакет на более ранних версиях). Если вы GUI консоль используете, то как минимум все BMP символы должны поддерживаться, и также  возможен вывод содержимого `sys.stdout` как текста без конвертации в байты. Если требуется конвертация в байты, то GUI консоль должна поддерживать utf-8/utf-16 чтобы все символы можно было бы представить.

Comment: @jfs: Вы правы, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент наиболее близкое решение - это исспользование пакета Console Exec. Установить его и в build system дописать

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "$file"],
    "target": "console_exec"
}
```

после этого все печатается, но весь вывод программ - выводится не в ST, а всегда открывается в консоли. В этом есть свои плюсы.

Но строго технически - это не отвечает на вопрос, как заставить ST печатать на русском. Если кто-то даст именно этот ответ - я назначу его ответ "ответом".

Comment: если у вас более одной версии Питона на машине стоит, то я бы вам рекомендовал [`py.exe` вместо `python.exe` использовать, для запуска `.py` файлов, чтобы можно было желаемую версию Питона прямо внутри скрипта в виде `#!`-строки указывать.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624186/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо. буду иметь в виду. я до этого через системные переменные указывал ту версию, что мне нужна. Это в винде тоже работает?

Comment: да, `py.exe` это  "Python Launcher for Windows" (вместе с Питоном поставляется).

Answer (score 1):

Только что столкнулся с той же проблемой, при настройке проекта для работы через VirtualEnv, в Repl и стандартный вывод начал выдавать такую же картину как в вопросе. Найденное решение простое, создаем свою настройку Build:

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "-i","-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "utf8",

"env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}, // Вот эта настройка делает вывод 
                                      // русских символов нормальным
}
```

Для Repl тоже самое правило:

```
    {
    "keys": ["f6"],
    "command": "repl_open",
    "args": {
        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "encoding": "utf8",

        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}, // Вот эта настройка

        "external_id": "python",
        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
        "type": "subprocess"}
    },
```