# отступ слева в cmd windows

Tags: windows, cmd, отступы

как сделать отступ слева в cmd windows? (чтобы он был ВСЕГДА при любых вводах и выводах)

поясню зачем: первые буквы сливаются с краем окна. и читать неудобно. см.картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в нормальных редакторах оставляют отступ слева - в виде "мертвого столбца" в 1 символ. Просто для визуального удобства, и чтобы глаза не ломать, вглядываясь, что там написано. 
Есть ли способ реализовать это в cmd винды? Любой. Правка реестра, настройки программы, доп.программы, что угодно.

см. пример. и сравните комфорт для глаз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за ответ. (хотя, надежды мало, что он есть)

вот пример в windows 7:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое отображение by design и не лечится. Попробуйте найти альтернативную программу с нужной фичей.

Comment: Читайте документацию prompt

Comment: Как вариант - создайте окно, окно cmd вложите в своё окно, background своего окна сделайте чёрным, подружите scroll.

Comment: Я бы сделал, как предложил nick_n_a, -  например, отступ пробелом: **prompt $S**. Для постоянного хранения формата для всех запускаемых окон консоли cmd: **setx PROMPT $S**

Answer (score 0):

Искал когда-то, не нашел. Так заложено по дизайну, не исправить.

Выберите другую терминальную программу и запускайте в ней cmd.exe. Например [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).