# Помогите с установкой Python в Sublime text

Tags: python, sublime-text

Я попытался по гайдам на ютубе установить `python 3` в `sublime`, но возникла проблема: когда я пишу `print("Что-нибудь на русском")`, то у меня выдаёт пустую строку. А на английском всё работает. Что делать?

Comment: Ищи лучше, такая проблема уже поднималась и решалась, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624364/sublime-text-3-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Comment: Ничего из этого не помогает

Comment: Уже нашел ответ

Comment: Нашли ответ - опишите его, возможно это поможет другим участникам, кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой. Правила сообщества предполагают, что участники не только получают от других - но и свой вклад вносят.

Comment: ответ нашел по ссылке которая была ранее в комментариях.( ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624364/… )1-ый ответ не помог,2-ой помог

Comment: "1-ый ответ не помог, 2-ой помог" - ответы могут менять порядой, например, если будет дан новый ответ.