# Запуск скриптов Python через cmd.exe без полного пути к скрипту

Tags: python, cmd, файловые-пути

Работаю на Windows 8.1 с Python 3.6. Мне нужно научиться использовать cmd.exe для запуска Python-скриптов. Нужно, чтобы я мог просто запустить cmd.exe и написать

```
python script1.py
```

и после этого файл `script1.py` был выполнен интерпретатором. При этом я не хочу писать полный путь к скрипту. Я настроил системную переменную `PATH`, так, чтобы в ней лежал путь к каталогу, в котором находится интерпретатор. Скрипт лежит в той же самой папке. И когда я просто запускаю интерактивный режим командой `python` из любого каталога, все работает хорошо. Но когда я пишу команду, приведенную выше, скрипт не запускается. То есть переменная `PATH` работает при поиске интерпретатора и не работает при поиске скрипта. Как мне сделать, чтобы я мог без написания полного пути к файлу запускать его?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1934675/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы запустить `some-command.py` Питон скрипт, который в одной из `%PATH%` директорий лежит, используя только имя команды (из любой директории):

```
C:\> some-command
```

нужно добавить `.py` расширение в `%PATHEXT%` переменную окружения:

```
C:\> echo %pathext%
```

и убедиться, что настроено приложение для запуска `*.py` файлов, к примеру, [pylauncher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) (`py.exe` — вместе с Питоном поставляется):

```
С:\> assoc .py
С:\> ftype Python.File
```

Если у вас несколько версий Питона установлено, то добавьте [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) на самом верху Питон-скрипта, чтобы указать желаемую версию Питона:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

См. [Как установить обе версии Python 2.x и 3.x на windows7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624135/23044).

Если директория присутствует в `sys.path` списке, то можно `-m` форму использовать, чтобы Питон модуль как скрипт запустить (из любой директории):

```
C:\> py -m some_module
```

в этом случае `some_module.py` не обязан в `%PATH%` лежать.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, вам нужно указать дефолтную директорию при запуске командной строки.

- запускаете regedit
- откроваете ветку `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
- добавляете новый параметр с типом `REG_SZ` (ПКМ > new > String Value) и присваиваете ему название Autorun
- в поле `value data` ( второе поле) вписываете нужный вам путь к директории где обычно у вас лежат скрипты, к примеру `CD C:\`
- сохраняете

Теперь при открытии cmd у вас по-дефолту будет открываться заданный путь

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего переустановить питон и при установке поставить галочку "добавить в Path".

Ну а руками попробуй в переменную Path добавить эти 2 строчки

```
C:\Users\Твой_Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\Твой_Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
```

Где "Твой_Пользователь" имя твоего пользователя.

А для скрипта добавь в PATH переменную "my_script" и путь к твоему файлу "script1.py". После этого будет все четко работать по

```
python %my_script%
```

Потребуется перезагрузиться.