# Как добавить программу на python в консоль (windows)?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd, консоль

Мне интересно, как запихнуть свою программу на python в cmd консоль на windows
по типу если у меня есть к примеру программа которая выводит просто "hello wolrd"
 и я хотел бы запускать её из консоли, не по директории через py "file" а например через команду there или типа того.

Comment: Ну сделай exe файл из исходников своей программы, добавь путь к нему в PATH, и запускай просто по имени.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Запуск скриптов Python через cmd.exe без полного пути к скрипту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773479/23044)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск скриптов Python через cmd.exe без полного пути к скрипту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773479/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-python-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-cmd-exe-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

Стоит попробовать

```
doskey my_script_python=python <abs_path_to_script>\my_script.py
```